# How to use Ionic 2 with phaser?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, phaser-framework

How I can use Ionic 2 with Phaser?

I found an [offical tutorial](https://phaser.io/tutorials/how-to-use-phaser-with-typescript) about using Phaser with Typescript using VS15 editor, but I can't figure out how to import and use it property with Angular2/Ionic 2.

Any ideas?